# Configuring Remote MySQL server for keycloak in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, keycloak

I am new to docker. We are having a keycloak instance that is running as a docker container. We are trying to configure docker container to store the data inside MySQL database which is running on other server. I am able to connect keycloak container with MySQL which is running in my local by using the following command.

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin 
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL \
  -e DB_ADDR=host.docker.internal \
  -e DB_PORT=3306 \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_USERNAME=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password  \
  jboss/keycloak
```

But if I am trying to access the database which is running on another machine by changing the DB_ADDR variable.

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL \
  -e DB_ADDR=<IP_ADDRESS> \
  -e DB_PORT=3306 \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_USERNAME=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
  jboss/keycloak
```

But I am getting `Access denied for user 'keycloak'@'<host_ip>'`.

I have created a schema called 'keycloak' and created user with GRANT ALL in the remote MySQL like below,

```
GRANT ALL ON keycloak.* TO keycloak@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbuserpassword';
```

Note: I am able to access this remote MySQL from my local MySQL workbench.

What would be the reason for this? Is there any network configuration i need to in my local machine? I am using ubuntu 20.04 machine. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: This link does not have configuration information regarding the keycloak running in docker.

Comment: Your local MySQL instance may listen network interface that bound to private docker network so its reachable from keycloak container, while your remote mysql is not

Comment: Was the `GRANT ...` SQL succesfull and did you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` SQL after?

Comment: Yes. and I am able to access the Remote MySQL from my MySQL workbench.

Comment: I found the issue. I have mentioned it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. It was a simple mistake. Keycloak docker image's environment variable name got changed in the newer version.
The updated command is below,

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL -e DB_ADDR=<IP_ADDRESS> -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=keycloak  jboss/keycloak
```

Hope this helps someone who is facing the same kind of issue.